# How to Update User With JWT Token When he Tries To Login in Nodejs and Reactjs with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a login functionality for my Reactjs Webiste using Nodejs express backend.

I want to set a JWT token when the user tries to log in and update that token in my mongoDB database and then verify the token on the frontend and save it to localStorage.

However, when the user tries to log in after registration, it returns back the result without the token, and thus not allowing the user to log in, unless he clicks the login button again, then my code would generate and update the user with the JWT token.

Why is this behavior happening? Why is the first response only returning the found user from the `findOne()` operation when i am resolving the result from the `findOneAndUpdate` operation?

Here is my code:

Auth Controller:

```
login(params) {
    params.email = params.email.toLowerCase();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.collection("Users").findOne({ email: params.email }).then((response) => {

          console.log(response)
          if(response) {
            bcrypt.compare(params.password, response.password, (err, success) => {
              if(success) {
                let token = jwt.sign({
                  name: response.name,
                  id: response._id
                }, proccess.env.JWT_SECRET);

                db.collection("Users").findOneAndUpdate({
                  email: params.email
                }, {
                  $set: { token: token, lastLogin: new Date() },
                }, function (e, s) {
                  if(e) {
                    console.log(e)
                    reject(e)
                  } else {
                    console.log("updated")
                    resolve(s)
                  }
                })
              } else {
                reject({msg: 'Incorrect email or password.'})
              }
            })
          } else {
  
            reject({msg: 'cannot log in user'});
          }

      })
    })
  }
```

Auth Router:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    let User = new models.User()
    let processes = [];
    processes.push(function (callback) {
        User.login(req.body).then(function (response) {
           
                callback(null, response);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error)
            callback(error);
        });
    });

    async.waterfall(processes, function (error, data) {
        if (!error) {
            return res.json({
                statusCode: 200,
                msg: 'User logged in successfully.',
                result: data
            });
        } else {
            return res.json({
                statusCode: 401,
                msg: 'Cannot login user.',
                error: error
            });
        }
    });

})
```

React Login.js:

```
const login = () => {
    axios.post('/login', data).then(async (response) => {
      console.log(response)
      if(response && response.data.result.value.token ) {
        localStorage.setItem("authUser", JSON.stringify(response.data.result.value.token))
        history.push("/")
        console.log(response.data.result)
      } else {
        console.log("ERROR")
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: _tries to log in after registration_ ... _unless he clicks the login button again_  Do I get it right, that login snippets in the question work just fine, and registration functionality does  not return expected response? If so, would you mind posting the code that you have problem with?

Comment: I don't understand the model part, are you using a hook in the model file?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDBs method `findOneAndUpdate` does return the old document by default.
In order to return the updated document pass `returnNewDocument: true` as option:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

In your case:

```js
db.collection("Users").findOneAndUpdate({
   email: params.email
 }, {
   $set: { token: token, lastLogin: new Date() },
 }, {
   returnNewDocument: true
 }, function (e, s) {
   if(e) {
     console.log(e)
     reject(e)
   } else {
     console.log("updated")
     resolve(s)
   }
 })
```

PS: You might should use `async` functions with `await`. This could make your code way more readable (at least within the User Model) :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i am still getting the same error, and getting back the old document first without the update. what is the problem?

Comment: Hmm that's pretty odd. Maybe try the `returnDocument` option then? May you're using an outdated mongodb version (Callbacks have been deprecated for a long time already and eventually been removed in the newest version: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/promises/#callbacks--deprecated-)

Answer (score 0):

This can help you.

In your model

```
async login(params) {
    params.email = params.email.toLowerCase();

    try {
        const user = await db.collection("Users").findOne({ email: params.email });

        if(!user) {
            throw {message: "Incorrect email"}
        }

        const vaild = await bcrypt.compare(params.password, user.password);
        
        if(!valid) {
            throw {msg: 'Incorrect email or password.'}
        }

        let token = jwt.sign({
            name: user.name,
            id: user._id
        }, proccess.env.JWT_SECRET);

        return db.collection("Users").findOneAndUpdate({
            email: params.email
        }, {
            $set: { token: token, lastLogin: new Date() },
        }, {new: true}); //FOR THE RETRIEVE NEW UPDATEs FROM MONGODB
    
    } catch(e) {
        throw e
    }
}
```